# How to make my own css rule?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question may be void. But I'm really interest to know that can I make my own css rule with jquery?

So, that I could assign in css stylesheet something like this:

```
div{
color: white;
background: red;
/*declaring my own css rule*/
myproperty: myvalue1; /*myvalue2, myvalue3*/
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into CSS preprocessors.

Comment: It's a good idea, and preprocessors would get you a long way, but I don't really see the benefit of doing something like this with jQuery. If you want to set a certain property to an element, and you are using jQuery anyway, why not stick to jQuery? If the user has JS disabled the property will not work any way. And if you provide your CSS file to another programmer and he sees your custom property, he has no idea what it does or where it is defined. For usability reasons, I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: You may think it's not a good idea. But how about if css3 features added with this idea?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by adding a new CSS style which the browser will not detect.

If, it is for data storage, you can look at adding `$('div').data('key', 'value')`